# Is there a term for the reduplication of letters?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, historical-change

We can see in some words, letters are reduplicated:

> Effect, apprehensive, abhorrent, blissful, affect, remiss

Sometimes these are caused by the evolution of their latin equivalents into English... However...

Is there a term for this letter reduplication in some words? Where two letters are next to each other?

Comment: Double letters? Why do you say reduplicated instead of duplicated?

Comment: What @Richard said. Per OED, ***reduplication*** has the special sense in linguistics: *repetition of a syllable or letter **that expresses a grammatical feature***. I don't think that applies to *all* OP's examples here.

Comment: Why not? Linguists do, though not when referring to alphabetic letters.

Comment: @John: Would say *effect* is "reduplication" then? I don't know diddly squat, obviously, but I'd have thought that one was just a matter of orthography.

Answer (score 2):

The duplication of letters is called *double letters*.

From [Your Dictionary](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/word-lists/words-with-double-letters.html):

> Double-letter words are words which contain at least one set of
>   letters used twice consecutively to make a certain sound, usually used
>   in the emphasis syllable in the word which contains them.

Comment: More specifically, all OP's examples contain  *double consonants*.